# Virtualize parts of a single frameworkelement

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, virtualization

I am looking for a way, for performance reasons, to have some sort of VirtualizedPanel where only part of the FrameworkElement that is in the viewport (within the width and height of the panel) is visually available, and the rest is Virtualized.
I thought of using a [ViewportControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.viewportcontrol%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), however, such control allows the elements within to be scrolled. I then found this [VirtualizingPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class, however, it seems like that class virtualizes on a per UIElement basis, i.e. you can't virtualize part of an FrameworkElement, it is either the whole element or nothing.
So I was wondering if there is a control I could use to achieve this. Or how the easiest, non-jerry-rigged way of doing this would be. i.e. I know I could just set the [ViewportControl.Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.viewportcontrol.bounds%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) = "0 0 0 0" to prevent a user from scrolling a [ViewportControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.viewportcontrol%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but that's not an elegant solution.

Comment: Can the user scroll the viewport, or do you only want to display a fixed section?

Comment: @CodeCaster Display only a fixed section. The user cannot scoll the viewport. The image, however, will scroll behind this viewport via an animation.

Comment: Then can't you simply put an Image control inside a Panel that's smaller than the image and scroll the image from code?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, but that wouldn't virtualize the Image? The whole Image would still be rendered, however it would be hidden by another rendered element, the control.

Comment: I don't think any virtualizing control really virtualizes it in the sense that parts not displayed don't take up memory. In the case of an image, it would mean the entire image is in memory anyway, as it has to be decoded to be displayed, and the virtualizing control would have to read the memory for parts of the image to display. I don't think that's readily available in a control, but it does seem trivial to implement. As soon as you have byte arrays containing the pixel data, you can skip and read through those and feed them to an image control as a `BitmapImage`.

Comment: That seems odd to me, as the way pinch to zoom is implemented in windows phone is via a viewportcontrol and an image within. So when you pinch in, the image scrolls and only part of it is rendered. If the viewportcontrol didn't work that way they would have just used a scrollviewer for the scrolling.